# In Google Sheets, Enter key moves selection

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, pressing the Enter key moves the cursor down a cell.  For example:

1. position cursor on the cell
2. type to enter text
3. press Enter key

   - Expect: Cursor stays on the cell I was just editing
   - Actual: Cursor moves down to next row

**Is there any way to turn off this behaviour in Google Sheets so the Enter key doesn't move the cursor?**  In Excel, there's a setting to choose what happens when the Enter key is pressed (to control if it moves to another cell or not).

Comment: Since you're probably not editing the same cell twice, it may help that you can "submit and move" not just down, but in any direction. Enter moves down, and Shift-Enter moves up. Tab moves right, and Shift-Tab moves Left.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option in Google Sheets. Pressing **<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>** key will always result in moving the cell selection by one cell downwards. As for the mouse cursor - it stays where left.

Your only option is to use the 3rd-party tool (**[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)** for example) which will "fix" this behaviour like for example:

1. detect that active window is Google sheet
2. upon pressing **<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>** key script will detect it and auto-press **<kbd>`Arrow Up`</kbd>** key